# ¿Cómo agregar varias rutas o urls amigables en un archivo .htaccess?

Tags: html, rutas

Estoy tratando de convertir mi app web con rutas o urls amigables, no lo he conseguido. Mis archivos que tengo son:

```
index.php
default.php
cursos/catCursos.php
```

El archivo catCursos.php esta dentro de una carpeta llamada cursos.

Lo que quiero hacer es que en la url en lugar de :

http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacionres/index.php

sea:

http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacionres/index

Al principio lo he logrado, pero tengo varios problemas, uno de ellos es.
Si en la dirección pongo:

http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacionres/index/

No funcionan detecta los estilos

El otro problema es que también tengo que hacer lo mismo con el archivo default.php es decir convertirla en ruta amigable:

http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacionres/default

Al agregar otra regla, me manda al archivo default siempre y sin estilos, entonces como podria hacer que si la persona pone un **/**  al final es decir: index/ tenga los mismos estilos o los detecte mas bien y como podria hacer que varios archivos sean con rutas amigables

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora en mi archivo .htaccess:

```
 **Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ default.php?url=$1 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cursos/catCursos.php?url=$1**
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debe definir las rutas y la expresión regular adecuada para cada una, en este caso utiliza la misma, `^(.*)`, para todas.
Quizás le sea útil esta [Guía básica de Expresiones Regulares](https://indexingdata.com/blog/analitica-web/guia-basica-expresiones-regulares/).

Después de `RewriteEngine on`, es muy importante poner las siguientes líneas:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

> Estas restringen la reescritura de URL solo a rutas que en realidad no
> existen. Esto evita que las siguientes reglas coincidan, por ejemplo,
> con example.com/images/logo.png. El primero evita los directorios
> existentes y el segundo significa ignorar los archivos existentes.

Lo anterior seguramente le soluciona el problema de las hojas de estilos.

Para el caso que usted plantea, creo que el siguiente código le puede funcionar

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index\/? index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^default\/? default.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cursos\/catCursos\/? cursos/catCursos.php [NC,L]
```

`\/?` indica que la URL puede o no terminar en /, por ejemplo index/.

> El indicador [NC] hace que RewriteRule coincida sin distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

> El indicador [L] hace que mod_rewrite deje de procesar el conjunto de reglas. En la mayoría de los contextos, esto significa que si la regla coincide, no se procesarán más reglas.

Ahora, si las URL reciben parámetros GET, entonces se complica un poco el asunto. Por cierto, el código que usted muestra (`index.php?url=$1`) sugiere eso, pero las URL de ejemplo (`http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacionres/index.php`) no. Este caso, manejar parámetros, lo puede encontrar en las dos primeras referencias.

Referencias:
[Using htaccess Files for Pretty URLS](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049)
[Simple Steps for Creating Friendly URL’s with PHP & HTACCESS](https://www.arpatech.com/blog/simple-steps-creating-friendly-urls-php-htaccess/)
[RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html)
[.htaccess case sensitive and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579652/htaccess-case-sensitive-and-mod-rewrite/16579927)